# copy and create new mysql setup on server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Iam a newbie for DB. I have a running database on godaddy's mysql setup. Now i have a new server whose access is not with me. I have to make a file which can install and create new mysql on that server plus it can copy and store specific tables from my current server database too.

I have to give this file to the person who is having the access so that he can execute it and can have all the content. How can i make such a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL's mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to take backup of your databases.

Alternatively, You can always backup your database using MySQL GUI tools like [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php).

I guess GoDaddy do not allows direct connection for mysqldump to work. In that case you can use SQLyog's HTTP tunneling capability.

Give the generated backup file (created through SQLyog or through mysqldump) to the person who has access and he will upload the file.

[Here is the SQLyog's documentation](http://www.webyog.com/doc/SQLyog/#Scheduled_Backups_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm) for taking Backup. Select Databases and Tables that you want to backup through wizard.

Hope it helps....